# PHP - checking if two dates match but ignoring the year

Tags: php, date

I have an array which will output a date. This date is outputted in the mm/dd/yyyy format. I have no control over how this outputted so I cant change this.

```
Array
(
    [date] => 04/06/1989
)
```

I want to use php to check if this date matches the current date (today), but ignoring the year. So in the above example I just want to check if today is the 6th April. I am just struggling to find anything which documents how to ignore the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( substr( $date, 0, 5 ) == date( 'm/d' ) ) { ...
```

Works only if it's certain that the month and date are both two characters long.

Comment: Use subtr($date, -5) to take the last 5 characters. This will work even when the month or day has 1 character ;-).

Comment: @JNDPNT I think you mean `substr( $date, 0, -5 )`, but it still wouldn't work: it wouldn't match `date( 'm/d' )` which always has 2 characters.

Comment: No I mean substr($date, -5). This will start from position langth - 5 till the end If I'm not caught by the heat :p.

Comment: Right, and the result is `/1989`.

Comment: Thanks :) I know (99% sure) my dates will always be two characters and after implementing this it appears to be working just as expected. I did play with a few of the below which also worked but this appeared to be so simple, so would be easiest to manage. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Came in a little late, but here’s one that doesn’t care what format the other date is in (e.g. “Sep 26, 1989”). It could come in handy should the format change.

```
if (date('m/d') === date('m/d', strtotime($date))) {
    echo 'same as today';
} else {
    echo 'not same as today';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will retrieve the date in the same format:

```
$today = date('m/d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$my_date = YOUR_ARRAY[date];

$my_date_string = explode('/', $my_date);

$curr_date = date('m,d,o'); 
$curr_date_string = explode(',', $date);

if (($my_date_string[0] == $curr_date_string[0]) && ($my_date_string[1] == $curr_date_string[1]))
{
    DO IT
}
```

This way, you convert the dates into strings (day, month, year) which are saved in an array. Then you can easily compare the first two elements of each array which contains the day and month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for compare duple conversion if you have a date.

$currentDate = strtotime(date('m/d',time())); --> returns current date without care for year.

//$someDateTime - variable pointing to some date some years ago, like birthday.
$someDateTimeUNIX = strtotime($someDateTime) --> converts to unix time format.

now we convert this timeunix to a date with only showing the day and month:
$dateConversionWithoutYear = date('m/d',$someDateTimeUNIX );
$dateWithoutRegardForYear = strtotime($dateConversionWithoutYear); -->voila!, we can now compare with current year values.

for example: $dateWithoutRegardForYear == $currentDate , direct comparison

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the other date into its timestamp equivalent, and then use `date()` formatting to compare. Might be a better way to do this, but this will work as long as the original date is formatted sanely.

```
$today = date('m/Y', time());
$other_date = date('m/Y', strtotime('04/06/1989'));
if($today == $other_date) {
    //date matched
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you can just compare the dates like this

```
 if(date('m/d',strtotime($array['date']])) == date('m/d',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()))) )
```

Comment: The `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()))` parameter is kinda crazy: the result === `time()`, or you could just leave it out completely and just do `date('m/d')`.